# Setting hidden form field's value to 'false' yet getting 'true' on server side

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hidden form field:

```
<input type=hidden id=blah1 value=true />
```

I have abutton, when clicked I do:

```
$("#b1").bind("click", function(){

$("#blah1").attr("value", "false");

});
```

But when I get the form value on the server side, it is 'true'.

Am I doing something wrong?

I even did this:

```
e.preventDefault();
$("#blah1").attr("value", "false");
alert( $("#blah1").attr("value") );
```

It alerted the value 'false'.

Comment: What about using the jquery function .val() instead of attr()? http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: Any chance you have more than one element with the same ID?

Comment: It seemed to work when I tested id. Try to wrap your html element attributes values in quotes : key="value", maybe that's what's messing with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did include the '**name**' attribute in your real code, no?

```
<input type=hidden id=blah1 value=true name=blah1 />
```

This still doesn't explain why you see "true" on the server side.  If you did include the "name" attribute on your hidden field, please post your server-side code.

Running the code you have posted here, once the "name" attribute is added, achieved the expected "False" result.

Answer (score 5):

Even aside from there being no 'name' attribute, you are setting the value to "false" as in a string, and a non-empty string will return true EVERY TIME.

```
$("#blah1").attr("value", "false");
```

should instead be

```
$("#blah1").attr("value", false);
```